# Visio 2010 UML Sequence diagram - lifeline does not have enough connectors

Tags: uml, visio, sequence-diagram

I am using Microsoft Visio 2010.

I am drawing a UML sequence diagram.

I added object Lifeline and started drawing diagram. Because the diagram is very long, at one point there would not be any more connectors to connect the arrows to. See this picture:[image: No more connectors]

I understand that probably it is not good idea to put so many processes on one diagram, but it seems to me to be the best way to describe the whole process. And I only need a bit more space to continue the diagram!

So, how to configure the lifeline to have more connectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read how to add more connection points at "[Add, move, or delete connection points](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/add-move-or-delete-connection-points-HP001231166.aspx)". This will allow you add connection points for the propose of creating the diagram however I don't know if this is sufficient for the UML model to know the source and destination of messages. This may be an issue if you are exporting the UML model to code or another tool.

Comment: This is not ideal (lot of manual work), but it is better than nothing. Thank You!